# Error message of "COM Surrogate has stopped working" after removing SOMETHING from PATH

Tags: windows, windows-10, crash

I keep getting a **"COM Surrogate (dllhost.exe) has stopped working"** error message that appears every 5 minutes on my Windows 10, This started after altering system `PATH` variable and removing some path I thought was not needed.

The removed `PATH` value was something like `/Windiws <??> Kit/`. The problem is I do not remember WHICH **"Windows Kit"** it was exactly.

What it could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this path or a valid similar path (confirm on your Windows 10 machine what it is), reboot and see if that resolves:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\`

This is path for Windows 10.